# Ruby set multipe values at once

Tags: ruby

What is the smarter way of doing this:

```
@entity.description = @resource.description
@entity.aliases = @resource.aliases
@entity.image = @resource.thumbnail
@entity.freebase = @resource.url
@entity.same_as = @resource.webpages
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
{:description => :description=, :aliases => :aliases=, :image => :thumbnail=,
 :freebase => :url=, :same_as => :webpages=}.each do |from, to|
  @entity.send(to, @resource.send(from))
end
```

But I doubt that this would increase readability of your code by much.  You might be better of leaving it as you have the code right now as writing it as short as I did obfuscates the code and makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than of handful of fields that are shared between two classes, you could consider packing them into a class, and simply assign (or clone) it. Then your code would look like:

```
  @entity.info = @resource.info
```

This, of course, requires that you have full control over the classes.